# Android - ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, econnreset

I have a problem that many of you have had when developing code to connect to the internet on android :

```
java.net.SocketException : recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

The code created is exactly the same as suggested by the Google Android Developer :

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Note that I included the properties below:

```
conn.setRequestProperty ( " Connection" , "close ");
```

and:

```
System.setProperty ( " http.keepAlive " , "false") ;
```

I was working fine, but now stopped in **some devices**.
That's weird. I have many users who are not having any problem, but some other users (who are using the same version of APP) are having this problem. It began on 26/december, with no explanation. It affects both GET and the POST.
I'm having this error in Galaxy Y - JellyBean (4.1.2).

Does anyone have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Have you find any solution to this problem. I am also facing the same issue.